# Realm DB React native Schema - type must be of type 'string', got (undefined) Error

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

This is my Schema for a Message history i'm getting from the API

```
export default class MessageSchema {
  static schema = {
    name: 'MessagesHistory',
    primaryKey: '_id',
    properties: {
      _id: 'string',
      text: 'string',
      createdAt: 'string',
      user: {
        uname: 'string',
        name: 'string',
        _id: 'string',
        avatar: 'string',
        rid: 'string',
      },
    },
  };
}
```

and this is my Realm Function

```
import Realm from 'realm';

import ChatlistSchema from './ChatlistSchema';
import MessageSchema from './MessageSchema';

export default function getRealm() {
  return Realm.open({
    schema: [ChatlistSchema, MessageSchema],
  });
}
```

Whenever I try to add the MessagesSchema to the Schema array, it gives me a promise rejection, and the data from the ChatlistChema object isn't loading also.

```
*Error: type must be of type 'string', got (undefined)
[native code]*
............
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One of your inserting values has not valid String type, Check your closure in debugger or ```console.log``` the value of inserting data.

Comment: are you getting your data from API for message schema? in your message schema, an object parameter is coming instead of a string, due to which your realm DB not saving your data. please check your data through postman or set a breakpoint in your app, and verify your data.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi i haven't inserted data yet, it shows this promise rejection right after i create the Schema and save the file.! Is that Thats fine?

Comment: You can see my working codes here and find what is the wrong with your code:
https://github.com/cybercoder/3cho/blob/master/client/src/db/index.js

Answer (score 1):

I had this error differently (`got (0)`) and the cause was there were some errors in a schema class. Some properties had a value 0 assigned instead of the data type name (double).

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the schema sometime back (which I completely forgot) due to which I was facing this issue.